# Ionic app starter project hangs on NPM install phase

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

When I'm trying to create a simple ionic app with 'ionic start' command, I see that ionic downloads a base app and the template indicated, but then I see 'Installing npm packages...' and it that never ends it's process (I have waited hours).
Ionic creates the myapp folder with files within it, but I don't know if it finally creates the ionic app to work with. If I put 'ionic serve' there is nothing on screen, even if I choose the tabs template.. or an error 'couldn't find ionic.config.json file'
is it a firewall issue? anyone has faced with this? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must update your ionic to beta version using:

> npm install -g ionic@beta